# What is metadata in Component.js?

Tags: sapui5, component.js

I am creating an app using Navigation and Routing concept and was unable to understand the metadata which needs to be specified in Component.js

What is the meaning of below :-

```
"controlId": "app",
"controlAggregation": "pages",
```

When I am checking the documentation [Component.js](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/01/87ea5e2eff4166b0453b9dcc8fc64f/content.htm) it is mentioned as -

```
targetParent: "myViewId",
targetControl: "app",
targetAggregation: "pages",
```

Can someone explain the difference between the above two and it will be helpful what exactly it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With below XML view code as an example, I will elaborate about the metadata configuration.

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="Demo.view.Main" displayBlock="true" height="100%">
    <App id="app">
    </App>
</core:View>
```

[`App`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.App.html) control is the root element for UI5 mobile application. It has `pages` aggregation as it extends from [`NavContainer`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#constructor).

```
targetControl: "app",
targetAggregation: "pages"
```

`targetControl` is specified with ID of control which is used to display the pages. In above XML, `App` control has "*app*" as it's ID.
So, all your views will be placed in `pages` aggregation of `App` control.

Now, you might be wondering how views can be placed in `pages` aggregation.
If you look at type of controls allowed in [`pages`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#getPages) aggregation is [`Control`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html). Any control which extends `Control` class can be placed in `pages` of `App`. As [`View`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html) is also Control it is valid to be added in `pages` aggregation.

So, all views in application are placed in `App`.

```
"targetParent": "myViewId"
```

`targetParent` is nothing but the view in which `App` control is placed.

Regarding difference between above and this

```
"controlId": "app",
"controlAggregation": "pages"
```

In newer version of SAPUI5, we specify configuration in *manifest.json* file instead of *Component.js* file. So, you will find this configuration their.
They are one and same but only with different names.

Answer (score 0):

> Following are the **Configuration Parameters for Navigation**

- routes :- The routes parameter defines an array of route configurations.
- config :- The config parameter defines the default values for route configuration.
- view :- The view parameter contains the name of the view that is created on the first time a route is matched. To place the view in a control, use targetAggregation and targetControl. Views are only created once.
- **targetParent** :- The target parent parameter defines the ID of the parent of the targetControl parameter.
- **targetControl** :- Views are put into a container control, for example a shell control or a NavContainer for mobile applications, or into any other container. The targetControl parameter contains the ID of this control.
- **targetAggregation** :- The target application parameter contains the name of an aggregation of the target control that contains views. A NavContainer, for example, has an aggregation called Pages and the shell container has Content.
- subroutes :- The subroutes parameter contains an array of routes and can contain the complete route configuration. Routes that are added to subroutes may have subroutes themselves.
- callback :- The callback parameter is an optional function that is executed after the route has matched.

Comment: But what is controlId and controlAggregation? What is the difference the one you explained and this?

Comment: even I am also searching controlId and controlAggregation. I think there is no any method in component.js